# Customizing Manual Workflow Initialization Page

Tags: workflow

I have a custom action button that initiates a manual workflow within a list. When this button is clicked, a default initilization page with the title "Start Workflow" appears with a "Start" and "Cancel" button embedded on it. What I'm trying to do is to apply some customization to this page's design (say adding a couple of sentences and changing the buttons' text)??

I have been looking inside designer but was not able to find the corresponding aspx file for the page; how would I go about changing it?

Thanks,
Wes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manually initiated workflow should create a XSN file.  This can be editied in InfoPath Designer and published back to the Sharepoint site.  When users initiate the workflow, they'll be taken to this page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eric, however I do not have access to InfoPath designer... I did make a search on the web for ways to modifiy the xsn without InfoPath; found some workarounds but have no luck making it to work. Sharepoint gave me a "This form cannot be opened in a Web browser. To open this form, use Microsoft InfoPath" error when initiating the workflow by custom button click. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wael/archive/2007/04/29/infopath-how-to-modify-the-xsn-file-and-the-inside-xml.aspx

Comment: I've been able to do what you described, Eric. However, being totally unknowledgeable about InfoPath, before I could publish my changes, I had to save an xsn template. But I had no idea WHERE to save it. Since I'm working on a SharePoint 2013 online site, should I have saved this template somewhere some where in that SharePoint 2013 online site? I didn't do that, and I wonder if that's going to bite me in the butt some time later...

Comment: It could be saved in a document library on the site or locally. It just has to be saved somewhere before it can be published.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I ended up saving my xsn templates in the same document library on the site, just in case someone else ever wanted to make alterations. I figure that if I saved them locally on my computer, the templates wouldn't be available.

Comment: Yep, I typically save them in the Site Assets library for the same reason.